# spring thymeleaf pass attribute to tabs

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

In my controller, I have set a object with name `currentAccount`. In the current main.html I can display its details by doing `<h1 th:text="${currentAccountant.name}" /></h1>`

I have tabs. the tabs are linked in the main page as below.

```
<!-- Tab content refers to this part -->
<div id="tabs-content" class="tab-content">
    <div id="home-tabs" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <div th:include="fragments/admin/companyProfile::companyProfile">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="settings-tabs" class="tab-pane fade">
        <div th:include="fragments/admin/accountSetting::accountSetting">b</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In `companyProfile.html` or `accountSetting.html`  when I do  `<h1 th:text="${currentAccountant.name}" /></h1>`  it doesn't work.

How do you pass on the object `currentAccountant` to the tabs?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [parameterized fragments](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#parameterizable-fragment-signatures). Make your fragments parameterized first:

`<div th:fragment="companyProfile(currentAccountant)"> ...`

You can apply this fragment by passing in the required parameters:

```
<!-- Tab content refers to this part -->
<div id="tabs-content" class="tab-content">
    <div id="home-tabs" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <div th:include="fragments/admin/companyProfile::companyProfile(${currentAccount})">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="settings-tabs" class="tab-pane fade">
        <div th:include="fragments/admin/accountSetting::accountSetting(${${currentAccount}})">b</div>
    </div>
</div>
```